Update qBittorrent nox port-forward setting from bash
How can I update the port forwarding setting of qBittorrent nox from bash?
I've tried to follow this example tweaked a little to work with PIA VPN but when I check the qBittorrent settings, the port forwarding setting hasn't been updated.
I have disabled authentication for local access, so that shouldn't be the problem.
 
This is the script I'm running
#read PIA port
forwarded_port=$(piactl get portforward)

echo $forwarded_port

WEBUI_PORT=8080 #qBittorrent port
web_protocol="http"

curl -k -i -X POST -d "json={"random_port": false}" "${web_protocol}://localhost:${WEBUI_PORT}/api/v2/app/setPreferences" # &> /dev/null
curl -k -i -X POST -d "json={"listen_port": ${forwarded_port}}" "${web_protocol}://localhost:${WEBUI_PORT}/api/v2/app/setPreferences" # &> /dev/null

The output of the script is
50483
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self';
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 11 Aug 2024 17:54:52 GMT
referrer-policy: same-origin
set-cookie: SID=6nnIxJuRqqupqkO8TcOVz76j5KeD6dhI; HttpOnly; path=/; SameSite=Strict
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self';
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 11 Aug 2024 17:54:52 GMT
referrer-policy: same-origin
set-cookie: SID=1IBcvH+n82fJA3DYv4QBRz2CxCK3u/Si; HttpOnly; path=/; SameSite=Strict
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block


This script properly sets the port forwarding setting in qBittorrent nox with PIA VPN.
#read PIA port
forwarded_port=$(piactl get portforward)

echo $forwarded_port

WEBUI_PORT=8080 #qBittorrent port
web_protocol="http"

curl -k -i -X POST -d "json={\"random_port\": false}" "http://localhost:${WEBUI_PORT}/api/v2/app/setPreferences"
curl -k -i -X POST -d "json={\"listen_port\": ${forwarded_port}}" "http://localhost:${WEBUI_PORT}/api/v2/app/setPreferences"


Another alternative using some automation with py-natpmp for ProtonVPN, but can be adapted for other VPN providers.
Two pieces script that you can mount at docker or run in your OS. Will check the open port and update your qBittorrent settigs.
I just mount dedicated place at my container, mounted at /usr/sbin, other at init scripting place and finally log file also at host.
https://gist.github.com/KaBankz/c5a08845e3c64fbae8053dc7d28f8191
Thanks to github.com/KaBankz
